# Why Tor cannot access /usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor?

Tags: tor

I'm getting the following error while installing Tor on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
[Warning] /usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor is not owned by this user (******, 1000) but by root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
[Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't access/create private data directory "/usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor"
[Error] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The above error means that you do not have permission to perform the installation.
So you need to become the root user.
Do this by typing
 `sudo -s`
in the terminal and you will be able to install tor.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to install the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) into `/usr/bin`. This directory has usually other permissions and it is advisable to install the Browser Bundle into another directory.

If you want to use it as a single user you can install into your home directory. Another useful place is `/opt` or `/usr/local`. Just create a new directory, extract the file contents there and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
sudo chown $USER -Rv /usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor
```